# How to generate letter sequence list in fish shell

Tags: bash, shell, fish, brace-expansion

In bash you can generate letter sequence easily as "{a..z}", for example

```
$ echo {a..z}
a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
```

How to do that in the fish shell instead?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fish doesn't support ranges in [brace expansion](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/index.html#expand-brace), only comma-separated values: `{a,b,c}`.

Thus, we are forced to search for a command capable of generating such sequence. For example, you can use Perl:

```
for c in (perl -e '$,="\n"; print ("a" .. "z")')
  printf ">> %s\n" "$c"
end
```

where [`$,`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#$,) is the output field separator.

*Output*

```
>> a
>> b
...(skipped)
>> y
>> z
```

You may find [this](http://hyperpolyglot.org/unix-shells#toc32) table useful.

Comment: On OS X and BSD, the `jot` command is useful: `jot -c - a z`.

Comment: Thanks, end up with hard code a list variable like
"set letters a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z"

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. Fish does support integer ranges.

Comment: @HubertGrzeskowiak can you give an example?

Comment: Some examples here: https://fishshell.com/docs/current/language.html#index-range-expansion. I probably should add that it's not ranges for generating numbers, but only for selecting elements from an existing list of values.

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use printf and seq.

```
echo -e (printf '\\\x%x\n' (seq 97 122))
```

This works by generating "\x61 \x62 \x63 ... \x7a" which is then interpreted by "echo -e" as hex character codes.

Answer (score 1):

Specifically to generate a-z sequence you can loop with, I think the most elegant and concise solution is to directly use bash with [fmt](http://linuxcommand.org/lc3_man_pages/fmt1.html) (which is available in most unix-like environment). You don't even need Perl and its more readable:

```
for c in (bash -c "echo {a..z}" | fmt -w1)
    echo "hello $c"
end
```

The logic goes like this:

1. The for-loop in fish shell loops through both array values and lines. If you can generate a-z each in its separate line, you can loop with that in fish.
2. The command `bash -c "echo {a..z}"` would give you a single long string in fish:

   ```
   a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z
   ```
3. The command `fmt -w1` would cut the space-separated strings into lines.

Result:

```
hello a
hello b
hello c
... (skipped)
hello z
```

This is amazing because you can take advantage of the same principle to reuse bash syntax in fish. Seems really flexible to me :-)

Answer (score -3):

Linux has the `seq` command for this, and it works with fishshell:

```
$ for f in (seq 1 10)
    echo $f
end
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10
$
```

Comment: Downvoted because this doesn't answer the question in any way.